# Ping command on iPad

Tags: macos, ios, ipad, ping

Is there some way by which a ping command or somewhat similar can be run on iPad ?

I am trying to do this as my wifi connection dies out if there is idle time even for a few mins though it works with continuous ping on desktop browsers.

So i want to simulate the same ping thing on iPad..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ouch - do realize that you will be working against two factors.

1. If the ping app is in the foreground - it's a easy project.
2. For it to run in the background (where it will do you any good) it has to play by the background task API - all of which are designed to prevent the usage of the CPU and preventing the WiFi from dropping. Even if it worked a while, it would be a bug and likely to break every time Apple updates it's OS.

Your battery life will be horrible - but that's your call since your network interruption might be more pain than a ten hour runtime. I have a solution that will work out of the box.

Get yourself a mapping app like [Runmeter](http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/runmeter-gps-for-running-cycling/id326498704?mt=8). It can be configured to upload a map to the internet every 5 minutes. It can also monitor a twitter stream, so you could set up a bot account to push updates more rapidly if the mapping alone didn't keep your iPad from detecting the WiFi as idle.

Comment: Is there a free app which does something similar?

Comment: I picked the one I knew would work - had I known of a free one, I would have featured it instead of a paid app. Perhaps you might edit your question - ping is how you solved your real issue on another platform - it seems you just want to prevent WiFi from dropping no matter what the mechanism. Also, the question is young - perhaps you picked the best words and it's just a matter of time till some better answers arrive.

Answer (score 0):

I just tried `Network Ping Lite` which worked well:

https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/network-ping-lite/id289967115?mt=8